# Why Mystique's claw got broken into two piece

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men

We know that Wolverine's claws are unbreakable and he can cut through any material using them. And Mystique can copy anyone one power completely, in fact in *Days of Future Past*, her capability is used to develop Sentinels.

In X-Men (first movie), there is a sequence where Mystique turns into Wolverine and tries to kill Cyclops. The original Wolverine intervenes and there is a fight sequence between both Wolverines. In the same sequence, when their claws strike, Mystique's (in form of Wolverine) claws broke into two parts. Why was Mystique not able to copy Wolverine's claws properly or does Wolverine somehow know some week point of his claws?

Comment: Related - Sort of - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59884/what-happens-to-parts-of-mystique-that-are-cut-off

Comment: It does not break, it gets lopped off.

Answer (score 7):

Mystique cannot copy powers. Her mutation, her DNA was studied and that gave Trask industries insight into unlocking a the power within her mutation that allowed more than what Mystique can do naturally.

Mystique also cannot copy everything. She cannot copy a substance like Adamantium. The claws may look metal, or her clothes may look like synthetic fibers, but they are still very much regular human skin cells. The claws are likely just regular nails.

Mystique can not copy a person's smell, as evident by Wolverine's reaction. And she cannot change her mass. She could change to look like the Juggernaut or Wolverine but would retain her normal ~130 lb weight.

#### In short, she can only change the shape and look of her cells, not the underlying chemical composition.

Comment: Not only that but the Adamantium was added to him as almost a plated metal, so she may copy him as per how he looks, but if her power is to copy power, she will be able to reveal claws and heal, but not have metal-plated claws/bones as they weren't part of his actual mutation.